# I Dismissed Dogmeat and cant find him anywhere

Tags: fallout-4

I dismissed him and told him to go to sanctuary while on the mission to destroy the institute i did this because I had Nick after i did this I could not find him anywhere and I'm on console so I cant use the moveto Command

Comment: There's a few doghouses scattered around Sanctuary, if you haven't scrapped them he could be 'sleeping' in one of those. After I had this problem I moved one to my main house and scrapped the rest, so he only has one 'home' to go to.

Comment: @kalina how is that a duplicate. Also check out Robotnik's answer use1327... thats your best bet.

Comment: @AshwinGupta "Where can I find dogmeat after dismissing him to sanctuary" vs "I dismissed him [dogmeat] and told him to go to sanctuary", are you SURE they're not duplicates?

Comment: @Testy - I saw your answer - Try waiting near the doghouse until about 3am when he should be sleeping. Try the Red Rocket Station as well, sometimes he shows up there.